# EE1 & SL Google Map

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I've an EE1 site (I know, just..quiet) running SL Google Maps to geolocate posts. It just started not responding from the CP side of things and I suspect that it's related to Google discontinuing support for an older API.

Any options here besides upgrading it all to EE2?  I just wasn't quite ready for that task yet.

Comment: what functions you want too keep? I check SL Google Maps  code and is no easy ways to switch api2 to api3. If you know gmap api3, it is takes 2-3h.

Comment: All of the functions..;)

Comment: Well, maybe not. I need the CP side of the Map presentation & geolocating, and the front-end side of feeding lat/long to Google for displaying markers on a map.

Answer (score 2):

Change Api2 to Api3 is almost the same as create  new ft.
From all exist geo add-ons for EE 1, you can try Geotagger (possible you need to speak with [Mightybigrobot](http://mightybigrobot.com/)). I don't have last version, but I believe that they was able to which to API3.

If they have this version, you just will needed to split data from current SL Google Maps to Geotagger fields (they have separate field for lat & long). Something like

```
UPDATE exp_weblog_data SET you_new_field_lat =  SUBSTRING_INDEX(you_old_field,',', 1), you_new_field_lng =  SUBSTRING_INDEX(you_old_field,',', 2)
```

Plus you will need to make small change in frontend using any of exist gmaps jquery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

There was another addon (free) called CoolLocation that worked for EE1 along these lines. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/coollocation

I suspect you'll have the same issues with the changes to the Google API, but it might be worth a shot. I'm not sure you can find it online anymore -but holler if you need a copy - I've got one.

If you've already got all your coords and aren't creating new entries, you can also roll your own new map using Mabox/Leaflet.

Comment: CoolLocation is one of the  most oldest gmaps add-ons for EE1.  It is used API2 and rebuild it will be more complicated task then SL Google Maps.

Comment: I got burned once by CoolLocation and how it was abandoned by its creators (even while it was still relevant). Not going there again..;)

Comment: well, it was field from pre-FieldFrame period. But as I remember, it is never work fine :)